# Very simple hypothesis testing problem

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Ok so I got asked a statistics problem the other day, and this is the problem:

Suppose that we survey $489$ randomly selected Country $X$ voters about whether or not they think Mr.A should leave the race, and $254$ of the $489$ voters say "yes". Test the hypothesis that greater than $49$% of Country $X$ voters believe that Mr.A  should quit the race. Find the $p$-value for this test. What does the value indicate, or mean?

1. I know that $H_0: \mu >0.49$, $ H_1:\mu \le 0.49$. How do I find the s.d and the $p$ value?, and how do I interpret the result of the $p$-value? I will appreciate the help.

Comment: Hint: The 489 voters are indistinguishable. It's like flipping a coin 489 times, and you get 254 heads. Now is that coin a fair coin. That's similar to your question.

Comment: So we treat this problem like binomial theorem, not even normal distribution? If so, then $254/489$ is that our $p$ value? or is the p value the $Binom cdf(489, 0.49, 254)$?

Comment: Is this ["push polling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_poll)?  Why $49\%$ rather than $50\%$?

Comment: Not a properly stated null hypothesis. The null hypothesis must _always_ contain possible equality: $=, \le,$ or $\ge.$ Do you mean $\ge?$

Comment: Ok now Im even more confused from reading these replies. The question was just someone who asked me in my class, I dont know where she got it from actually...

Comment: I will remind you that binomial distribution approaches normal as N goes to infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'll answer a similar question that does not have the difficulties
mentioned in the Comments.

**Question.** In a survey of 489 randomly chosen voters, 254 say the candidate should
drop out of the race. What can we say about the proportion $p$ of all
voters who share this view?

**Confidence interval.** A straightforward method is to use the data to make a 95% confidence
interval (CI) for $p.$ We estimate $p$ by $\hat p = 254/489 = 0.517.$
Then a 95% CI is of the form

$$ \hat p \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}}.$$

For your data, this gives $(0.475, 0.564).$ So the relatively small
sample from the poll is not enough to settle whether more than half
of the voters feed the candidate should withdraw.

---

*Notes:* (1) Technically, this
CI assumes there are more than about 5000 voters in the county. If there
were fewer, the CI would be somewhat shorter. (2) This CI uses a normal
approximation to the binomial distribution, which should be reasonably good.
(3) There is another formula, slightly more complicated than this one, that
might be considered more accurate, but it gives $(0.475, 0.563),$
which is not different for practical purposes.

---

**Test of Hypothesis.** Now, you wonder if we can be reasonably sure that the population percentage
in favor of the candidate's withdrawal exceeds 49%. We know that $\hat p = 0.517 > 0.49,$ but the issue is whether $\hat p$ is *significantly* greater than 0.49.

We test the hypothesis $H_0: p \le 0.49$ against the alternative $H_a: p > 0.49.$ We use the $=$-sign in $H_0$ to say that the observed number in favor
of his withdrawal is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 489, p = .49)$ and ask
for $P(X \ge 254),$ which is called the P-value of the test. The P-value is the probability of a number greater than or equal to the observed number.

One can use software to compute $P(X \ge 254) = 1 - P(X \le 253) =  0.1045$. In R statistical software the computation is as follows:

```
 1 - pbinom(253, 489, .49)
 ## 0.1044754
```

So there is more than one chance in 10 of getting a value as large as 254
(hence $\hat p$ as large as 0.517), even if only 49% of the population favors
withdrawal. Obviously, $\hat p = 0.17 > 0.49,$ but we have shown that
this difference could have been due to sampling error in a sample as small as 489.  [*Note:* You could also use a normal approximation to evaluate $P(X \le 254).$ The result would be about the same, but perhaps only accurate to two
decimal places.]

Usually one does not reject a null hypothesis unless the P-value is smaller
than 5% and here it is larger than 10%, so we do not have statistically significant evidence that
the true population proportion exceeds 0.49. In view of the CI computed
earlier, this is hardly a surprise because the CI includes 0.49 as a
'believable' value of $p.$ [*Note:* If you had tested $H_0: p \le .50$ agains
$H_a: p > .50$ as suggested in one of the Comments, then the P-value would 
have been about 0.21-- even larger.]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. So since our $p$-value is $0.1045$, we reject the null hypothesis $H_0: P\le 0.49$?, but since the significance level is not given in the question, how do we know when to reject or not? Is $5$% the standard comparison level?

Comment: Reject $H_0$ at level $\alpha$ if P-value < $\alpha,$ So don't reject at 5% level here. When significance level is not stated, 5% is usually intended.

Comment: So in this problem we just assume the $\alpha$ is $5$%? But in actuality since it is not given, we do not reject anything, as the $p$-value has no $\alpha$ to test it against?

Comment: I'd use $\alpha = 0.05$ and fail to reject because of that.

Comment: So we can use $\alpha = 0.05$ even if its not specifically mentioned in the problem?